# Python 3.4 ctypes message box doesn't open with other code included

Tags: python, ctypes

Normally this code works fine when called.

```
import ctypes

def message_box(title, text):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, 1)
```

But when it's used with other code it hangs at the line where message_box is called.

```
import ctypes

def message_box(title, text):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, 1)

while True:
    time = input("Enter time of the reminder in the format 'HH:MM': ")
    if (len(time) != 5):
        print("\nInvalid answer\n")
        continue
    if (time[2] != ":"):
        print("\nInvalid answer\n")
        continue
    try:
        hours = int(time[0:2])
        minutes = int(time[3:5])
    except:
        print("\nInvalid answer\n")
        continue
    if not (0 < hours < 23 or 0 < minutes < 59):
        print("\nInvalid answer\n")
        continue
    break

message_box("Example_title", "Example_text")
```

Comment: Works for me.  Most problems with `ctypes` are the result of not defining `argtypes` and/or `restype` for the function being used.  Differences in Python version and OS are more likely to cause problems without specfiic definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it.

In the fourth argument for the message box, you need to put in values separated by pipes ('|'). From my limited testing, the MB arguments define the buttons that the user can click, apart from MB_SYSTEMMODAL which brings the window to the front. The ICON arguments define what noise the window makes as it pops up as well as a little image in the window denoting its purpose.

```
MB_OK = 0x0
MB_OKCXL = 0x01
MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
MB_YESNO = 0x04
MB_HELP = 0x4000
MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 4096
ICON_EXCLAIM = 0x30
ICON_INFO = 0x40
ICON_STOP = 0x10

def message_box(title, text):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, MB_OK | ICON_INFO | MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```